# express.js: stylus wouldn't create css file

Tags: node.js, express, stylus

My file structure:

```
App
  node_modules
  views
    index.jade
    layout.jade
    stylesheets
      style.styl
  public
    stylesheets
  app.js
```

My code:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var stylus = require('stylus');
var app = express(); 

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); 
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    // app.use(express.bodyParser()); 
    app.use(express.methodOverride()); 
    app.use(app.router); 
    app.use(stylus.middleware({
        src: __dirname + '/views',
        dest: __dirname + '/public'
    })); 
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    articleProvider.findAll(function(error, docs) {
        res.render('index.jade', {
            title: 'Blog',
            articles: docs
        });
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log("listening in on port 3000...");
```

layout.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        block content
```

When I run this on my local machine, I get

```
404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/stylesheets/style.css
```

error. I'm pretty sure the css file is not being automatically compiled by Stylus. What am I missing here?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://clock.co.uk/tech-blogs/a-simple-website-in-nodejs-with-express-jade-and-stylus looks prommissing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635078 may be helpfull

Comment: possible duplicate of [express + stylus + jade, nothing gets compiled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198042/express-stylus-jade-nothing-gets-compiled)

Comment: I've looked at all those links but still didn't have success. This is weird but if i find a solution I'll post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use a compile function with stylus.

Check the tutorial by [Ben Gourley](http://clock.co.uk/blog/a-simple-website-in-nodejs-with-express-jade-and-stylus) and the stylus [middleware documentation](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/middleware.html)

Also check my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228953/how-can-i-use-express-jsstylus-with-nib/24979730#24979730 for a modified compile function.

```
 function compile(str, path) 
 {
   return stylus(str)
     .set('filename', path)
     .use(nib())
     .import('nib')
 }
```

and add it to app.use(stylus.middlewre like this:

```
 app.use(stylus.middleware
    src: __dirname + '/views',
    dest: __dirname + '/public',
    compile: compile
 )
```